# Using Geodata Service in ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, enterprise-geodatabase

Can I use Geodata service in ArcGIS JavaScript API 3.1?

Background: I have simple map service and the all attribute data is stored in SQL Server database. I want to perform query operation on map service in JSAPI (and data should come from database.)

> > I have only database access and I cannot create the Geo-database.
> >     I can't attach the data to shapefile (it's too large)

I searched on Google and asks few people so they told me that publish the data as "geodata service" but according to API documentation JSAPI (3.1) do not support Geodata service.

Also in JSAPI examples it's not mentioned clearly.

So what should I do?

Software: ArcGIS Server 10.1, ArcGIS Java script API 3.1, ArcSDE

Comment: I am also reviewing similar post             http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21092/how-to-load-spatial-data-into-arcgis-javascript-api-application-from-sql-server?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Convert the data into Json Format and use in your application.You  can write handler that can convert Data from sql into JSON.[Sql Data to Json](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=6d28a606369c43fd9a6f929541ae7c93).Usin Json you can Create feature set and feature collection and display feature layer.